# How to specify geo radius command additional arguments with Spring Data Redis Repositories?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring Data Redis to save some *addresses*, each contains a `location` property of type `Point` that holds the geo-coordinates of the particular address. Also, the property is annotated with `@GeoIndexed`. Like what described here: [Geospatial Index](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.indexes.geospatial).

My `Address` model looks like this:

```
@RedisHash("addresses")
public class Address {    
    @Id
    private String id;    

    @GeoIndexed
    private Point location;    
}
```

I was able to get all nearby addresses to a given point and distance with this repository query:

```
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, String> {
    List<Address> findByLocationNear(Point location, Distance distance);
}
```

My problem is that the returned *addresses* by the above query are unsorted but I need them to be sorted from the nearest to the furthest (`ASC` option described here: [GEORADIUS - Redis Command](https://redis.io/commands/georadius)).

So, generally, I need a way to pass additional arguments to this query such as sorting or limiting the results (any option of [GEORADIUS - Redis Command](https://redis.io/commands/georadius)).

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Have you any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass this problem by implementing your solution using the `GeoOperations` class.

In this way, you can use the `RedisGeoCommands.GeoRadiusCommandArgs.limit(n)` and you will be able to limit the number of results to the first n matching.

Take a look here on the official documentation of Spring Data Redis: [GeoRadiusCommandArgs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisGeoCommands.GeoRadiusCommandArgs.html)

You can find also some examples directly into the Spring Data Redis tests.

**Update:**

This is the final code I came to by implementing a new `service` method instead of the `repository`:

```
public class AddressService {
    private final StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

    public AddressService(StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate) {
        this.stringRedisTemplate = stringRedisTemplate;
    }

    public List<Address> findByLocationNear(Point location, Distance distance) {
        Circle within = new Circle(location, distance);
        GeoRadiusCommandArgs args = GeoRadiusCommandArgs.newGeoRadiusArgs().sortAscending().limit(10);

        GeoOperations<String, String> geoOperations = stringRedisTemplate.opsForGeo();
        GeoResults<GeoLocation<String>> nearbyLocations = geoOperations.radius("addresses:location", within, args);

        // Convert geo results into addresses
        List<Address> addresses = ...;

        return addresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, exactly I solved the problem by using `RedisTemplate` and `GeoRadiusCommandArgs` as you referred here. I will update your answer with the final code I came to.

Comment: Happy to help you @knemr57 . If you're able to discover how to create a complex query with filter (where conditions) applied on the data let me know. Seems that the Lattuce library has some problem for me in this sense.